# DEBUG For Linux

Tags: linux, assembly

I'm now extending more my x86 Assembly knowledge and one of the best tools for learning is [DEBUG](http://math.berkeley.edu/~vojta/). When I was learning Assembly(past 4 years) I was on Windows, but now I'm on Linux Ubuntu and the DEBUG tool is only for Windows. Then I want to know is there is any port or equivalent for Linux.

*Remember that I don't want to debug my code, but do things like the command* `-r`, `-t`, `-e`...

Comment: Improved the link and specified the features I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-r` = `info registers`
`-t` = `stepi`
`-e` = no direct equivalent; taviso wrote a [macro](http://my.opera.com/taviso/blog/show.dml/248232) providing similar functionality

`debug` with no args starts up with some blank 64k of memory that you can play around with; GDB doesn't.  That really only made sense on DOS anyhow; you'll have to start with some binary.

Maybe assemble some blank slate like so?

```
$ echo .globl main >a.s
$ echo main: >>a.s
$ for i in {1..65536}; do echo 'int $3'; done >>a.s
$ cc a.s
$ gdb a.out
(gdb) run
```

Comment: I heard that the GAS backend that assembles this code is designed to accept the (perfect) output of GCC - its error reporting thus not being that user friendly.  I can't find the reference to this though.

Comment: It doesn't matter: we're assembling something so stupid and dumb that it can't possibly fail anyways. :-D  This creates an object where `main` is just a 64kB sequence of breakpoints (`nop` and `.byte 0` didn't work well in my testing).

Answer (score 4):

gdb is pretty much *the* debugger on the Linux platform. You don't specify what features you require, but it probably has them :)

Comment: Sorry for this, now I've specified the feature that I want.

Answer (score 4):

I used DEBUG mostly to assemble rather than "debugging"... if that's your goal,

- [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/) is a good assembler with more similar syntax
- [Use gdb](http://www.cs.umbc.edu/portal/help/nasm/nasm.shtml#gdb) to then run the code, allow disassembly, and examine memory

Answer (score 0):

gdb - the [GNU project debugger](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) is the Linux standard debugger. It is far more powerful than DEBUG (if by that you mean the old DOS tool) and you should really learn at least the basics of how to use it if you are programming on Linux.